# How to get which line number is executing at runtime in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am developing an app in which I need the line number of the method which which is currently executing at runtime.

Answer (score 4):

You don't say why you want the line number, but as Objective-C is a superset of C, you can use the `__LINE__` pre-defined macro (useful with the `__FILE__` pre-defined macro) to do things like logging:

```
NSLog(@"Hi!  I'm at %s:%u", __FILE__, __LINE__);
```

You might also find the `__FUNCTION__` pre-defined macro useful too:

```
NSLog(@"Hi!  I'm in method %s at %s:%u", __FUNCTION__, __FILE__, __LINE__);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly: Build for profiling, then profile (Instruments should launch) then use  Apple's `System Trace` tool! Good luck!